# Count of Total/Read/Unread/Unread older than 2 days e-mails in Outlook shared inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to count outlook message items stored in a shared mailbox on the current day and store these values into 4 categories:
"Total", "Read", "Unread", "Breached"(Unread for more than 2 days since it came to the inbox).
Every category is working fine, besides "Breached", as it does not count them at all.
What i'm having problem with, is making a correct if statement with double condition that checks if the e-mail is unread as well as if it's older than 2 days.

I've tried iterating through items with other loops but it did not help. I've also tried to use RecievedTime function but it didn't work either. The problem occurs within the following fragment of code:

```
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items.Restrict("@SQL=%today(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
        j = j + 1
        If olMail.UnRead = True Then
            i = i + 1
        If DateDiff("d", olMail.CreationTime, Now) >= 2 And olMail.UnRead = True Then
            h = h + 1
        End If
        End If
```

Here's the rest of the code, for the sake of privacy I've changed names of inboxes and

```
Sub CountSelectedItems()
    Dim olApp As Application
    Dim SelItems As Outlook.Selection
    Dim IntRes As Integer
    Dim StrMsg As String
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim Fldr As Folder
    Dim processed As Integer

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set SelItems = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    Set Fldr = GetFolderPath("exemplaryName\Inbox")

    i = 0
    j = 0
    h = 0
    For Each olMail In Fldr.Items.Restrict("@SQL=%today(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
        j = j + 1
        If olMail.UnRead = True Then
            i = i + 1
        If DateDiff("d", olMail.CreationTime, Now) >= 2 And olMail.UnRead = True Then
            h = h + 1
        End If
        End If
    Next olMail


    processed = j - i
    StrMsg = "Total: " & j & vbNewLine & "Processed: " & processed & vbNewLine & "Not processed: " & i & vbNewLine & "Breached: " & h
    IntRes = MsgBox(StrMsg, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count Selected Outlook Items")
    Call CreateNewMail(j, processed, i, h)
End Sub
' Use the GetFolderPath function to find a folder in non-default mailboxes
Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function

GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function

Sub CreateNewMail(total, processed, unprocessed, breached)
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem
    Dim MyDate

    MyDate = Date

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With NewMail
         .Subject = "Processed/Unprocessed mailbox " & Date
         .To = "exemplaryEmail@example.com"
         .Body = "Hi" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "As of " & MyDate & " the current KM Mailbox messages status is: " & vbCrLf & "Total: " & total & vbCrLf & "Processed: " & processed & vbCrLf & "Unprocessed: " & unprocessed & vbCrLf & "Breached: " & breached & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Kind regards"
         .Display
    End With

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If you restrict items to those received today, there will never be any older than today.

Comment: What about a solution that implements the following functionality:
1.Check e-mails that came in today, count them, and check which are read/unread in the moment of launching macro
2. Check e-mails that have been on the inbox for the last 2 days, if some of the are unread - mark them as breached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
'
' If desperate declare as variant


Sub CountItemsInFolder()

    Dim strMsg As String

    Dim allItems As items
    Dim unreadItems As items

    Dim agedItems As items
    Dim agedUnreadItems As items

    Dim fldr As folder

    Dim processed As Long

    Dim allItemsCount As Long
    Dim unreadItemsCount As Long

    Dim agedItemsCount As Long
    Dim agedUnreadItemsCount As Long

    Dim strFilterUnread As String
    Dim strFilterAged As String

    'Set Fldr = GetFolderPath("exemplaryName\Inbox")
    Set fldr = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Debug.Print vbCr & "** folder: " & fldr

    Set allItems = fldr.items
    allItemsCount = allItems.count
    'Debug.Print "items in folder: " & allItemsCount

    ' ** filter for unread items
    strFilterUnread = "[unread]=true"
    'Debug.Print strFilterUnread

    Set unreadItems = allItems.Restrict(strFilterUnread)
    unreadItemsCount = unreadItems.count
    'Debug.Print "unread items in " & fldr & ": " & unreadItemsCount & vbCr

    ' ** filter for aged items
    strFilterAged = "[ReceivedTime]<'" & Format(Date - 2, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"
    'Debug.Print strFilterAged

    Set agedItems = allItems.Restrict(strFilterAged)
    agedItemsCount = agedItems.count
    'Debug.Print "aged items in " & fldr & ": " & agedItemsCount

    Set agedUnreadItems = agedItems.Restrict(strFilterUnread)
    agedUnreadItemsCount = agedUnreadItems.count
    'Debug.Print "aged unread items in " & fldr & ": " & agedUnreadItemsCount & vbCr

    processed = allItemsCount - unreadItemsCount

    strMsg = "Total: " & allItemsCount & vbNewLine & "Processed: " & processed & vbNewLine & _
             "Not processed: " & unreadItemsCount & vbNewLine & "Breached: " & agedUnreadItemsCount

    Debug.Print strMsg & vbCr
    'MsgBox strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count Selected Outlook Items"
    'Call CreateNewMail(allItemsCount, processed, unreadItemsCount, agedUnreadItemsCount)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,

seems to be working very well, but this function counts all the e-mails recieved throughout mailbox lifetime, what i'd need is e-mails recieved within today (The day i launch this macro)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Find/FindNext or Restrict methods of the `Items` class. To count the items for a specified range of days you can apply a filter to the `Items` collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter. Then you just need to check the `Count` property.

For example, I have noticed the following code:

```
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items.Restrict("@SQL=%today(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%")
        j = j + 1
        If olMail.UnRead = True Then
```

Each time the loop iterates you apply the filter anew and get a new collection back. Instead, I'd recommend calling the `Restrict` once and then checking the `Count` property.

You also need to combine property conditions for the search term. There is no need to check the `UnRead` property in the loop.

Read more about the `Restrict` method in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)