# Need to set a date range or a 'lookback x' days in VB Macro that pulls data from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

**What I am attempting:** I am trying to extract emails from a custom subfolder. The emails contain a list of employees that we hire or terminate. The email fires daily. Every month we do an audit in which we have to go through each email and manually copy and paste the userIDs. I created a macro to extract all the emails in the subfolder but I cannot figure out how to filter to look back 45 days versus extract all the emails from the box. I cant figure out how to correct the order as well. I tried myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True  but it didnt work.

*note: the box only contains the emails we use for auditing.*

**Issue: 1.** All the emails in the sub-inbox are extracted successfully, but the latest emails (see pictures) received are not in order, they appear at bottom of the list. All the prior emails are in the correct descending order.

**Issue 2:** I am trying to add a filter to look back 45 days only. I don't need the entire box to be extracted just the last 45 days from the day I run the macro.[the order of extraction start at 5/30] [order is off at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhGpd.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVDyi.jpg)

**Question: 1.** How can I get the list in order so it can show the emails by ReceivedTime descending.

**Question2:** How can I add a lookback 45 days to the macro script?

```
Sub Extractor()


Range("A2:H30000").Clear
Dim OLApp As Outlook.Application
Set OLApp = New Outlook.Application


Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace

Set ONS = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim MYFOLDER As Outlook.Folder
 
Set MYFOLDER = ONS.Folders("fakeemail@fakeemail.com").Folders("Inbox")
Set MYFOLDER = MYFOLDER.Folders("NewHires")

Dim OLMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Set OLMAIL = OLApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set myItems = MYFOLDER.Items
myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True


For Each OLMAIL In MYFOLDER.Items
 
Dim oHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set oHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 
  

Dim oElColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
With oHTML
.Body.innerHTML = OLMAIL.HTMLBody
Set oElColl = .getElementsByTagName("table")
End With
 
Dim t As Long, r As Long, c As Long
Dim eRow As Long

For t = 0 To oElColl.Length - 1
    eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    For r = 0 To (oElColl(t).Rows.Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (oElColl(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
            Range("A" & eRow).Offset(r, c).Value = oElColl(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r
    eRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    
    
Next t
 
 
Cells(eRow, 1) = "Sender's Name:" & " " & OLMAIL.Sender
Cells(eRow, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
Cells(eRow, 1).Font.Color = vbWhite
Cells(eRow, 2) = OLMAIL.ReceivedTime
Cells(eRow, 2).Interior.Color = vbBlue
Cells(eRow, 2).Font.Color = vbWhite
Range(Cells(eRow, 1), Cells(eRow, 2)).Columns.AutoFit
Next OLMAIL


Range("A2").Select

Set OLApp = Nothing
Set OLMAIL = Nothing
Set oHTML = Nothing
Set oElColl = Nothing

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Q1 `For Each OLMAIL In myItems`. The expectation on this Q & A site is one question per post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count of Total/Read/Unread/Unread older than 2 days e-mails in Outlook shared inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195997/count-of-total-read-unread-unread-older-than-2-days-e-mails-in-outlook-shared-in)

Comment: Thank you that worked! and I guess I doubt the issues I was having were somehow related. I will edit and ask about the range in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the list in order so it can show the emails by ReceivedTime descending.

You need to sort items in the descending order. For example, you do that in the code by using the following line:

```
Set myItems = MYFOLDER.Items
myItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
```

But later in the code the sorted collection is ignored:

```
For Each OLMAIL In MYFOLDER.Items
```

So, to get the right results you need to re-use the sorted collection for the loop:

```
For Each OLMAIL In myItems
```

> How can I add a lookback 45 days to the macro script?

Use the `Restrict` or `Find`/`FindNext` methods of the `Items` class. The following search criteria can be used to get items for a date range specified:

```
    Dim datStartUTC As Date 
    Dim datEndUTC As Date 

    datStartUTC = oPA.LocalTimeToUTC(Date) 
    datEndUTC = oPA.LocalTimeToUTC(DateAdd("d", 45, Date)) 

    'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " < '" & datEndUTC & "'"
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)